# Koans score_project and understanding the method needed

Tags: ruby

I am currently working through the Ruby Koans and I am stuck on the scoring project. First of all, I am having a hard time evaluating the instructions and laying it out in terms of what I am suppose to do. Secondly, I am not sure if I am on the right track with the method score I wrote below. My questions is - Is there a way to understand these instructions better? Also, with the score method I wrote, I am still not passing the first test. I think I must understand what I need to do first but I can't figure it out. Any help and simple explanations or direction is appreciated.

Thank you.

Greed is a dice game where you roll up to five dice to accumulate
points.  The following "score" function will be used to calculate the
score of a single roll of the dice.

A greed roll is scored as follows:

A set of three ones is 1000 points

A set of three numbers (other than ones) is worth 100 times the
   number. (e.g. three fives is 500 points).

A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points.

A five (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 50 points.

Everything else is worth 0 points.

Examples:

```
score([1,1,1,5,1]) => 1150 points
score([2,3,4,6,2]) => 0 points
score([3,4,5,3,3]) => 350 points
score([1,5,1,2,4]) => 250 points
```

More scoring examples are given in the tests below:

Your goal is to write the score method.

```
def score(dice)

(1..6).each do |num|
amount = dice.count(num)

if amount >= 3
  100 * num
elsif num == 1
  100 * amount
elsif num == 5
  50 * amount
else 
  0
    end
  end
end

# test code for method 

class AboutScoringProject < Neo::Koan
  def test_score_of_an_empty_list_is_zero
  assert_equal 0, score([])
end

def test_score_of_a_single_roll_of_5_is_50
  assert_equal 50, score([5])
end

def test_score_of_a_single_roll_of_1_is_100
  assert_equal 100, score([1])
end

def test_score_of_multiple_1s_and_5s_is_the_sum_of_individual_scores
  assert_equal 300, score([1,5,5,1])
end

def test_score_of_single_2s_3s_4s_and_6s_are_zero
  assert_equal 0, score([2,3,4,6])
end

def test_score_of_a_triple_1_is_1000
  assert_equal 1000, score([1,1,1])
end

def test_score_of_other_triples_is_100x
  assert_equal 200, score([2,2,2])
  assert_equal 300, score([3,3,3])
  assert_equal 400, score([4,4,4])
  assert_equal 500, score([5,5,5])
  assert_equal 600, score([6,6,6])
end

def test_score_of_mixed_is_sum
  assert_equal 250, score([2,5,2,2,3])
  assert_equal 550, score([5,5,5,5])
  assert_equal 1100, score([1,1,1,1])
  assert_equal 1200, score([1,1,1,1,1])
  assert_equal 1150, score([1,1,1,5,1])
end

end
```

Comment: You almost got it, you only miss two things.
How do you accumulate the results inside the switch case? You will need to save the addition from each iteration.
And if the amount equals or greater than 3 and the num is 1 you need to do something else.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done:

```
def score(dice)
  score = 0
  return score if dice == nil || dice == []
  quantity = dice.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|result,element| result[element] +=1; result}
  score += quantity[1] >= 3 ? 1000 + ((quantity[1] - 3) * 100) : quantity[1] * 100
  score += quantity[5] >= 3 ? 500 + ((quantity[5] - 3) * 50) : quantity[5] * 50
  [2,3,4,6].each {|x| score += x * 100 if quantity[x] >= 3 }
  score
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash for score instead of writing switch-case

```
def score(dice)
  score_map = {
    1 => 100,
    5 => 50
  }
  cluster = dice.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, number| hash[number] += 1; hash}

  cluster.inject(0) do |sum, (num, count)|
    set_count = count / 3

    sum += num == 1 ? 1000 * set_count : num * 100 * set_count
    sum + (score_map[num] || 0) * (count % 3) # use 0 if score of num dosn't exist
  end
end
```